# fill form and repopulate select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm a newbie here, so please be gentle. I have some basic troubles connecting the dots. I have a simple form. See below.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="json.php">
    <input id="okr_id" type="text"/>
    <input id="okr_name" type="text"/>
    <select id="org_id">
    </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to fill in the form and repopulate the select box based on the information sent by a ajax (json) request.

The json is formatted as can been seen below:

```
    
    

    {"data":[{"okr_id":"1","okr_name":"Dennis","org_id":"2"}],
     "select":{"org_id":[{"base_id":"1","base_name":"Team A"},
                         {"base_id":"2","base_name":"Team B"}]}}
```

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Comment: What a hostile comment. I'm a newbie here, but not on (web)development.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for( var i = 0; i < result.select.org_id.length; i++ ) {
    $('#org_id').append( '<option value="' + result.select.org_id[i].base_id + '">' + result.select.org_id[i].base_name + '</option>' );
}
```

Let me fiddle that for you :-)

https://jsfiddle.net/8hq7jybq/1/

Comment: Not quite what I meant, but I helped me in the right direction (not completely there, though).